# How to call "this" in mapState in VUE component?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex

```
import { mapState } from 'vuex'

...mapState({
   user: (state) =>{
     return _.filter(state, data => {
       return _.includes(this.allUserIds, data.id)
     } )
   }
})
```

in this case, I won't call this.allUserIds in map state

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use `() => {}` function syntax because it is binding `this` too early.

```js
...mapState({
  user(state) {  // <--- here
    return _.filter(state, data => {
      return _.includes(this.allUserIds, data.id)
    })
  }
})
```